# Some part of Javascript/jQuery not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me figure out why my code of jQuery/javascript is just not working for the multiplication function? All the functions plus the multiplication function are working on my browser and android. The other functions except the multiplication one also work on IOS safari. I can't seem to see what's wrong with the multiplication function on IOS seeing as I've basically wrote all of these very similar to one another

```
function additionUncertainty() {
      $(".button-addition").next(".Answer1").remove();
      var Dx = $("input[name=Dx-add]").val();
      var Dy = $("input[name=Dy-add]").val();
      var sum = Math.sqrt((Dx * Dx) + (Dy * Dy));
      if(sum == 0) return 0;
      $(".button-addition").after('<p class = "Answer1"> Answer: ' + 
      sum.toFixed(4) + '</p>');
}   

$("input[name=Dx-add], input[name=Dy-add]").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(".button-addition").click();
    }
});

$(".button-addition").click(function() {
    additionUncertainty();
 });
// End Of Addition/Subtraction Uncertainty 

function multiplicationUncertainty() {
    $(".button-mult").next(".Answer").remove();
    var Dx = $("input[name=Dx-mult]").val();
    var Dy = $("input[name=Dy-mult]").val();
    var x = $("input[name=x-mult").val();
    var y = $("input[name=y-mult").val();
    var sum = Math.sqrt((x*x*Dy*Dy) + (y*y*Dx*Dx));
    if(sum == 0) return 0;
    $(".button-mult").after('<p class = "Answer"> Answer: ' + sum.toFixed(4) + '</p>');     
}
$("input[name=Dx-mult], input[name=Dy-mult], input[name=y-mult], input[name=x-mult]").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(".button-mult").click();
    }
});
$(".button-mult").click(function() {
    multiplicationUncertainty();
});

//End Of Multiplication Uncertainty

function divisionUncertainty() {
    $(".button-div").next(".Answer").remove();
    var Dx = $("input[name=Dx-div]").val();
    var Dy = $("input[name=Dy-div]").val();
    var x = $("input[name=x-div]").val();
    var y = $("input[name=y-div]").val();
    var sum = (Math.sqrt((x*x*Dy*Dy) + (y*y*Dx*Dx))) / (y*y);
    if(sum == 0 || sum !== sum)  return 0; //NaN is unequal to itself, sum !== sum is used to test this.
    $(".button-div").after('<p class = "Answer"> Answer: ' + sum.toFixed(4) + '</p>');      
}
$("input[name=Dx-div], input[name=Dy-div], input[name=y-div], input[name=x-div]").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(".button-div").click();
    }
});
$(".button-div").click(function() {
    divisionUncertainty();
});

//End of Division Uncertainty

function powerUncertainty() {
    $(".button-pow").next(".Answer").remove();
    var Dx = $("input[name=Dx-pow]").val();
    var x = $("input[name=x-pow]").val();
    var n = $("input[name=n-pow]").val();
    var sum = (Math.pow(x, n-1))*Dx*n;
    if(sum == 0 || sum !== sum) return 0;
    $(".button-pow").after('<p class = "Answer"> Answer: ' + sum.toFixed(4) + '</p>');  
}
$("input[name=Dx-pow], input[name=n-pow], input[name=x-div]").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(".button-pow").click();
    }
});
$(".button-pow").click(function() {
    powerUncertainty();
});
```

Comment: In the absence of any error messages, it's unlikely anyone will be able to assist. You can use iOS JavaScript debugger in Safari to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @miken32 So what should I use to debug it? Not sure how to go about this

Comment: "You can use iOS JavaScript debugger in Safari to narrow down the problem." Plug your iOS device into a Mac and open up Safari, use the Develop menu.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Is the `<p class = "answer">` inserted, but only shows 'Answer:' (without the sum)?  Or does the code fail before that point?

Comment: The paragraph element just doesn't come at all for that multiplication function on IOS Safari, so nothing shows up, it's as if no paragraph element is created. The rest of the functions work fine on IOS though